# Derivation of an integral identity

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, statistics, expectation

I've come across a lemma in a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03657v1.pdf). I do not understand the derivation of Lemma 5.1 in the addendum of the paper. It goes as follows (included as png):

[image: Lemma 5.1]

I do not understand the last step. Why can one pull $f(x,y)$ into the inner-most integral, transforming it into $f(x',y)$? What are the suitable regularity conditions of $f$?